# Visual Studio 11 italic parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm currently trying out the new Visual Studio 11 which can be obtained [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543). And I must say I do like it :) I have only some small nuisances with it...

VS11 now supports some new coloring options for keywords/typedefs/etc and also for parameters you get passed in a function. Some hipster at Microsoft decided they should display italic... And ugh it is ugly and I can't turn it off! In the 'Fonts and Colors' section only bold can be ticked and unticked. Does anyone know some registry/xml-file hack to change the font to non-italic again?

Comment: Open a new question for each of your bullet points.  If you want to tell a story about trying VS2011, fine, but use links between questions for that, instead of asking a question with multiple unrelated parts.

Comment: You're right, I decided to go with the question most suitable for SO, the rest I'll e-mail to MS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing values for the following reg-key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Studio\11.0\FontAndColors\{*****}\***** FontFlags
```

Comment: It's called CppParameterSemanticTokenFormat FontFlags, and it is set to 0. Changing the value only gets me a bold face one time or italic the other time. I think VS checks for bits on this value... So no succes :(